# Remove "Import from Excel" option for all user levels except "Superuser"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, import-from-excel, security-roles

I am new to Dynamics 365. I have a requirement to remove "Import from Excel" option for all user levels except 2 security groups. How can I achieve it? I have multiple security roles available out of which only 'Super User' and 'Admin' roles need to have 'Import from Excel' option.

If I am removing the 'Data Import' from 'Core Records' of each security roles, will that help? Or What all need to be changed in order to achieve this?

If I am changing the 'Data Import' from 'Core Records' tab in Security role, will the 'Import from Excel' be removed from all the entities as well as Data Management section for those users?

-----Updated----
This is the latest privilege Below privilege is not working in one environment but working on others. what could be reason for its not working in one environment?.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the security roles you can set if a user is allowed to do data imports. The following privileges are relevant:

- Data Import – Except Assign & Share all privileges at user level
- Data Map – Except Assign & Share all privileges at user level
- Import source file: Except Assign, Share & Delete all privileges at user level
- Web Wizard: Read
- Web Wizard Access Privilege: Read
- Wizard Page: Read

It's a bit of trial & error finding out what works for your requirement. Import privileges will work for all entities in the system. However, the user doing data imports still needs at least the Create and Read privileges for the specific entity.

As an alternative you could

Comment: Thank you Henk.

If am removing any of the above mentioned privileges for a role(eg. System Customizer ), will the Import functionality get removed for that role?

Also, if I need to make these changes in various environments such as Dev, Test, Prod etc, should I do it manually in each environment? Or is there any way to export and import these changes?

Comment: Yes, it would be removed for that role. Add the role to your solution. Export the solution and import it into the target environment.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and when I am removing one of the privilege(eg. 'Create' from Data Import), the 'Import from Excel' option is removed. So, which is the privilege(safest one) to be removed for getting the 'Import from Excel' option unavailable for multiple Security Roles or should I remove all the above privileges. If I am removing all the above privileges will it affect any other functionalities or is there any other functionality I need to check specifically which can be affected by this change.

Comment: It is just about how fine grained you wish to trim these privileges. Often withdrawing one privilege at the data import level will be sufficient to meet your goal. The Read privilege for example is in many cases a basic requirement to get things accessible. You need to experiment here, because unfortunately this is not documented in all details.

Comment: As suggested above, my solution worked in my Dev and test environments, but when I imported the same Security role to Prod, it is not working. What could be the reason? I have attached the screen shot of the latest privilege in the question.

Comment: Do the users have exactly the same roles? Other roles assigned to users can mitigate the settings of the role you tuned.

Comment: Yes. The user is having exactly same role(only one role). Is there anything to be considered while importing role. All other changes related to roles are working as expected.